# all $(k,n)$ satisfy $(2n+1)^{n}=8n^k+2n^2+1$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

find all natural number $(k,n)$ that satisfied $(2n+1)^{n}=8n^k+2n^2+1$.

anyone have idea? help at least with some hint please. thanks in advanced.

Comment: If you expand the left side by binomial theorem, the last two terms are $2n^2+1$ which you can cancel from both sides.

Comment: okay i'll try it. ${)$

Comment: B. Goddard but, how to expand them since they are same, n and n, not x and n or the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice,

$$(n) \equiv (2n+1) \equiv (-1) \space mod\space n+1$$

Thus the equation;
$$ (2n+1)^n = 8 n^k + 2n^2 + 1$$

becomes;
$$(-1)^n \equiv 8(-1)^k + 2(-1)^2 + 1 \space mod\space n+1 $$

Since $n,k$ are the exponents of $-1$, four cases can be made.

Case 1: 'n' is even and 'k' is even.

Since 'n' and 'k' are even, the equation becomes; $$1 \equiv 8 +3 \space mod\space n+1 \rightarrow 10 \equiv 0 \space mod\space n+1 \Rightarrow n+1|10 $$

Since 'n' is even, n+1 is odd.

Thus $n+1=1 \space or\space 5 \Rightarrow n = 0 \space or\space 4$ but $0$ is rejected as it's not a natural number.

Find 'k' by substituting 'n=4' into the original equation,

$$ (2(4)+1)^4 = 8(4)^k + 2(4)^2 + 1 \rightarrow (9)^4 = 8(4)^k + 33 \rightarrow \frac{6561-33}{8}= 4^k = 816 = 3 \cdot 92 $$
$$ 4^k= 3 \cdot 92$$

Since the RHS has 3 as a multiple, 'k' cannot be a natural number.

Case 2: 'n' is even and 'k' is odd.

Since 'n' is even and 'k' is odd, the equation becomes;
$$ 1 \equiv -8 + 3 \space mod\space n+1\rightarrow 6 \equiv 0 \space mod\space n+1\Rightarrow n+1|6$$

Thus $n+1=1$ or $3 \Rightarrow n = 0$ or  $2$ but $0$ is rejected because it is not a natural number.

Find 'k' by substituting 'n=2' into the original equation,
$$(2(2)+1)^2 = 8 (2)^k + 2(2)^2 + 1\rightarrow 5^2 = 8(2)^k + 9 \rightarrow \frac{25-9}{8}=2^k=2$$
$$2^k=2 \Rightarrow k=1$$

Thus $(1,2)=(k,n)$ is solution.

Case 3: 'n' is odd and 'k' is even.

Since 'n' is odd and 'k' is even, the equation becomes;

$$-1\equiv 8 + 3 \space mod\space n+1 \rightarrow 12 \equiv 0\space mod\space n+1\Rightarrow n+1|12$$

Since 'n' is odd, 'n+1' is even.

Thus $n+1=2,4,6,12\Rightarrow n=1,3,5,11$

Find 'k' by substituting $'n=1,3,5,11'$ into the original equation,

$$(2n+1)^n = 8 n^k + 2n^2 + 1\rightarrow \frac{(2n+1)^n -2n^2 -1}{8}=n^k$$
$$\frac{\ln{\frac{(2n+1)^n -2n^2 -1}{8}}}{\ln{n}}=k$$

You will find that none of these values of 'n' give an natural number solution of 'k'.

Case 4: 'n' and 'k' are odd.

Since 'n' and 'k' are odd, the equation becomes;

$$-1\equiv -8 + 3 \space mod\space n+1\rightarrow 4\equiv 0 \space mod\space n+1 \Rightarrow n+1|4$$

Thus $n+1=2 \space or\space 4 \Rightarrow n=1 \space or\space 3$

Find 'k' by substituting 'n=1 or 3'into the original equation,

$$ 3^1 = 8 + 3$$ is never true so $n\not= 1$

$$ (2(3)+1)^3 = 8(3)^k + 2(3)^ + 1 \rightarrow (7)^3 = 8(3)^k + 19 \rightarrow \frac{343-19}{8}= 3^k=40.5$$ 
$$3^k=40.5$$
Since RHS is not a natural number, neither is 'k'

Thus the only solution is $(1,2)$

Comment: This a hint, I can post the rest of the solution if you need any more help

Comment: I need the solutions please sir.

Comment: how can from $1 \equiv 11 \pmod(n+1)$ be $10 \equiv 0 \pmod(n+1)$ ?

Comment: $1 \equiv 5 \space mod\space 4 \leftrightarrow 5 \equiv 1 \space mod\space 4$